# If two excel cells match and criteria is "Yes" then count

Tags: excel, count, match

I am trying to create a report to count how many tickets users are creating and how many tickets they are closing. I have raw data exported daily and want to utilize that data for a count.

Example:
If user # (cell) on Sheet 1 matches with user # (cell) on Sheet 2 and criteria is "Yes" then count as 1

I'm currently typing in the user's # (101) for each cell to count, but wondering if I could match the cells instead of typing each user # manually
`=COUNTIFS(DATA!$G:$G,"101",DATA!$M:$M,"YES")`

I tried this below and the number was way off.
`=SUMPRODUCT(ISNUMBER(MATCH($A:$A,DATA!$G:$G,0))*(DATA!$M:$M="Yes"))`

Comment: replace the `"101"` with the cell reference: `A2` and copy the formula down the data set.

Comment: I tried putting `A2` but the count isn't working. To give additional context, sheet 2 has all the data and sheet 1 is the report.
I tried changing it to:
=COUNTIFS(A13:DATA!$M:$M,"Yes")

But now I'm getting the #!VALUE! error

Comment: `=COUNTIFS(DATA!$G:$G,A13,DATA!$M:$M,"YES")`

Comment: Thank you Scott! That did it! I was adding `"A13"` when I didn't need the `""`. I appreciate your help!